# How to save messages received through msg/ command in windows cmd

Tags: cmd

If I receive a message sent using the msg/ command in windows cmd, It comes written in a dialog box.
I want to save that message somewhere like in a file or anything. 
Is it possible, and if so, how can it be achieved?

Comment: You can use `Ctrl-c` to copy the dialog contents. Also, by default the message information is stored in the system event log.

Comment: copying it worked..but i am making a project on encryption and decryption in c so I am sending an encrypted message, So how should i decrypt the received message automatically, without any user involvement ?